# Update price in text field from selection

Tags: jquery

I have a text field in which we manually enter a price.

I then have a select field with packages that can be selected by the user. Depending on what is selected, I want the price of the package to be added to the text field.

My HTML is...

```
 <label for="_cost">Total Cost:</label><br />
        &pound;<input type="text" name="_cost" id="_cost" value="" placeholder="0.00" />

<label for="_package">Select an Event Package:</label><br />
                <select name="_package" id="_package">
                <option value="" data-price="0.00">No Package</option>

                <option value="test" data-price="100.00">Test</option>
                </select>
```

What is the best way to do this with jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("select").on("change", function(){            
        $("#_cost").val( $(this).find(":selected").data("price") );  
    });
});
```

Comment: @Mike You haven't included jQuery in your fiddle. You can do that from the menu on the left.

Comment: Oops! Thanks... the problem is that the value of the data-price field is over writing the text field completley. I need to keep the value manually entered in the text field and add the select data-price to it

Comment: also, I have other select fields on the form and if I change those, the text field resets to 0

Comment: I stopped al select fields changing the value by adjusting to... $(document).ready( function(){
    $("#_package").on("change", function(){            
        $("#_cost").val( $(this).find(":selected").data("price") );  
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

something like this seems to work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                base = 0;
                $("#_cost").on("keyup", function () {
                    base = $('#_cost').val();
                });
                $("#_package").on("change", function(){            
                    var total = (base * 100 + $(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100 ) / 100;  
                    $("#_cost").val(total.toFixed(2));
                });
            });
```